# serialize part of an object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an C# object that hold a big list (10-100MB) and some other properties. I want to serialize the object, but I don't want to serialize the list. is there any easy way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of serialization do you want? XML, Binary,...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is tagged [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), this could be as simple as adding `[XmlIgnore]` to the appropriate property:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<Foo> Items {get;set;}
```

Then just use `XmlSerializer` as normal.

If it needs to be controllable (sometimes yes, sometimes no) then an alternative is to add:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeItems() {
    // your logic here
}
```

This pattern is recognised by many serializers, `XmlSerializer` included.

Comment: Thanks, the first option seems to work :) can you explain again the second one?

Comment: @Amir the serializer basically checks for a few name-based patterns it cab use. If there is a public bool ShouldSerialize*() method (for the appropriate named member), it calls that method during serialization to decide whether to serialize that member or not

Comment: Simiarly, the serializer checks for a property named `*Specified` (for the appropriate named member).

Comment: @Brian that is double edged: the plus is that the setter can be hijacked to acknowledge data; however, properties often interfere with other binding frameworks - only some of which check for [Browsable(false)] etc

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by serialization loading the object from database, then I can recommend [`NHibernate`](http://nhforge.org/), you simply mark, you want to enable lazy-loading on the List and your object will return, with `Items` set to null (and if you are still in transaction, `Items` will load, after and only after attempting to access it; if you are out of transaction already, you will get a nullPointer exception I think)... but basically, [Lazy-loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) in any its kind is certainly a principle, you should keep an eye on.

**EDIT**: *missed the tags, shame on me*

Comment: Serialization usually means "to a blob/clob". Database work is usually "persistence/materialisation". But yes, the terms are sometimes used rather interchangeably.